# Best approach to showing how you have saved your company a lot of money in an interview/resume?

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-search, job-change

I am working in a product based company.When I joined the company, there were two large issues with the product.These issues were causing a lot of refunds.The issues were known for about 6 months but nobody knew what was causing the issues.I caught both of these issues and solved which saved my company a lot of refund cases and in turn saved them a lot of money.About one third of the people were asking for refunds.

I don't like to brag and I wouldn't like to come off as a self praiser in the interview.But a lot of seniors have told me that if you have saved your company a lot of time or money then these are huge plus points.

So I was wondering how do I mention this in my interview or resume(if I should even discuss this thing at all)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the question you say: **About one third of the people were asking for refunds.**

That is your starting point:

> Responsible for a major modification to the product which reduced the number of requests for refunds from 33% to less than 10%

You might add a few details or be prepared to discuss them.

Did you get an award for this? You could use some of the text from the writeup/justification paperwork.

It is hard to say that you were responsible for additional sales, because that was also a result of other changes to the product, or a price change, or additional advertising.

Of course it could be argued that these other changes increased the sales into areas that wouldn't be as likely to trigger a refund request.

Comment: Also, if they ask for reference, OP could give someone's number that know about those incident well enough.

Answer (score 3):

This should be a bullet point in your resume. Example

> 2010-2012: Company XXX: software developer
>
> - found two major bugs that saved $250000 yearly in product return cost

Comment: what do I do if I don't know how much money I have saved? Obviously the number of people asking for refunds vanished but how do I know how much I have saved?

Comment: Ask the person in charge of money.

Comment: @workerBoy you'll have to come up with an estimate - on the lines of how many man-holes are there in new york city? How many total customers were there (for that product), what was the refund % before you fixed the bug. How many of those can be directly attributed to those bugs. What were the total customers after bugs were fixed - how many refunds post bug fix. Whats the estimate cost of each refund (this could be higher than sticker price of product). Now you have a ball park number that you probably saved.

Comment: I would not like this on a resume. If the bugs were hard to find or fix, I don't care if they cost the company $250000 or $25, I'm interested in your ability to find bugs.

Comment: @MrFox I hope you care about more than that. I can find hundreds of trivial bugs each day - when can I get a job?

Comment: @enderland Where did I say trivial? My point is that QA/Dev should not be the ones putting price tags on bugs. If that bullet point said "found and fixed critical bugs under tight deadlines" it would be WAY better than "averted $XYZ cost to the comany" -> Does this person REALLY know how much a given bug costs a company? How? Are they a senior manager in the operations department or are they just throwing crap on the resume hoping to impress people with numbers (it has numbers, it must be true!)?

Comment: @workerBoy - If you do not know how much money you saved then how can you claimed that you saved them alot of money...

Comment: @MrFox, I have things like this in my resume and they almost always get me the interview. Many hiring managers are intersted in profitablity of the company and want people who are also interested in it no matter what their technical field. It is a plus that separates you out from the pack. Now you should be able to show you have the technical knowledge too.

Comment: Without a lot of additional information; this is a meaningless metric.  Some people might find it impressive though.  It's very hard to realistically/accurately equate a value to the bug (if a program is worth X - how much is each bug worth if you can't prove you've found all of them?)  Beyond that, the difficulty of the bug has is not necessarily related to the monetary value.  A huge trading company might move staggering amounts of money around, a trivial bug could save millions.  A very difficult bug on a customer's website might only prevent a mild visual annoyance.

Answer (score -1):

A resume or interview is different from a normal social interaction. A prospective employer is trying to find the best candidate for the job, so a candidate telling them accomplishments is doing them a service by providing more information on which to base the decision. As long as the information is presented in a factual manner, it's not inappropriate to "self praise". Just keep the focus on how the information would help *the company*, rather than how great it makes *you* look.

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace -- note that this question was answered over 4 years ago. Please take a look at some more recent questions as well that need feedback.